# Replacing partial with AJAX in Rails 4 can't find my view

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm trying to change a button class with an upvote and downvote and try to use the build-in AJAX functionality for it. I think that everything is there, but when running it it's still missing a specific view.

*models/oneliner.rb*

```
has_many :general_connections
has_many :users, through: :general_connections
```

*models/general_connection.rb*

```
belongs_to :oneliner
belongs_to :user
```

*models/user.rb*

```
has_many :general_connections
has_many :oneliners, through: :general_connections
```

*controllers/general_connection.rb*

```
def like_oneliner
  @oneliner = Oneliner.find(params[:oneliner_id])
  current_user.general_connections.create(oneliner: @oneliner)
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to :back }
    format.js
  end
end

def unlike_oneliner
  @general_connection = GeneralConnection.where("oneliner_id = ? AND user_id = ?", params[:oneliner_id], current_user.id).first
  @oneliner = @general_connection.oneliner

  @general_connection.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_to :back }
    format.js
  end
end
```

*views/oneliners/index.html.erb*

```
<h5><%=t 'index.title' %></h5>
  <div class="row">
    <ul class="collection">
      <% @oneliners.each do |oneliner| %>   
        <%= render partial: 'list', locals: { oneliner: oneliner } %>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

*views/oneliners/_list.html.erb*

```
<li class="collection-item avatar">
  <i class="circle black"><%= oneliner.users.count %></i>
  <span class="title"><%= oneliner.title %></span>
  <p><%= timeago_tag oneliner.created_at, :nojs => true, :limit => 100.days.ago %> / <%=t 'list.employee' %><%= oneliner.user.name %>
  </p>

  <% if !joined(oneliner) %>
    <%= form_tag(onelinerlike_path, remote: true) do %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag 'oneliner_id', oneliner.id %>
        <%= button_tag 'thumb_up', id: "#{ dom_id(oneliner) }", class: "secondary-content material-icons grey-text", style: "background-color:white;border:none;" %>
    <% end %>
  <% else %>
    <%= form_tag(onelinerunlike_path, remote: true) do %>
      <%= hidden_field_tag 'oneliner_id', oneliner.id %>
      <%= button_tag 'thumb_up', id: "#{ dom_id(oneliner) }", class: "secondary-content material-icons orange-text", style: "background-color:white;border:none;" %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</li>
```

*views/general_connection/like_oneliner.js.erb*

```
$('#<%= dom_id(oneliner) %>').replaceWith(<%= j render partial: 'oneliners/list', locals: {oneliner: @oneliner} %>");
```

The like and unlike methods do works, but I'm getting the following error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `oneliner' for #<#<Class:0x007fe4f15056a8>:0x007fe4f5408eb8>):
1: $('#<%= dom_id(oneliner) %>').replaceWith(<%= j render partial: 'oneliners/list', locals: {oneliner: oneliner} %>");
app/views/general_connection/like_oneliner.js.erb:1:in `_app_views_general_connection_like_oneliner_js_erb___1501586799937634897_70310671877500'
app/controllers/general_connection_controller.rb:7:in `like_oneliner'
```

Can anyone help me out?

**Update:** changed the `controller` and `.js.erb` sections according to some tips from `user4382423`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The like and unlike methods do works, but I'm getting the following error:

```
> ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template
> general_connection/like_oneliner, application/like_oneliner with
> {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:js, :html], :variants=>[],
> :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :arb, :jbuilder]}.
```

Your template must be in **general_connection** folder not in **general_connections**

Comment: Oops, yes, missed that one. But it still isn't working. The new error is:

`ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method "oneliner"for #<#<Class:0x007fe4fb0d3648>:0x007fe4f7a2a2b8>):
    1: $("#<%= dom_id(oneliner) %>".replaceWith(<%= j render partial: "oneliners/list", locals: {oneliner: oneliner} %>");
  app/views/general_connection/like_oneliner.js.erb:1:in "_app_views_general_connection_like_oneliner_js_erb___1501586799937634897_70310691947700"
  app/controllers/general_connection_controller.rb:7:in "like_oneliner"`

Comment: it because oneliner is local variable you should change it to instance variable..

e.g @oneliner and change locals: {oneliner: oneliner} to locals: {oneliner: @oneliner}.. and that work for you :)

Comment: I've changed the `.js.erb` locals into `locals: {oneliner: @oneliner}`, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: have you change local variable in controller too??

Comment: change in app/controllers/general_connection_controller.rb

Comment: Yes, see the updated question (I've changed the controller and `js.erb`). Still the same error.

Comment: I solved it: I also had to add an instance variable to the first part of the `.js.erb`. So now that first part looks like this: `$('#<%= dom_id(oneliner) %>')`. Thanks for your help!